# Можно ли запретить создание полигона/круга границами?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хотелоась бы узнать, есть ли в апи яндекс карт возможность не дать пользователю создавать

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите ваш вопрос подробнее. Что значит "запретить создание границами?" И как пользователь создает полигон/круг?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ограничить область карты, которая будет доступна пользователю. Соответственно, он сможет рисовать полигон только в пределах области.
В песочнице карт есть пример ограничения области
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/restrict_map_area